Logs are not transferred to the Audit server
I have two virtual machines on Ubuntu.
on the client machine the following Auditd settings:
file: : /etc/audit/plugins.d/au-remote.conf
active = yes
direction = out
path = /sbin/audisp-remote
type = always
#args =
format = string

file:  /etc/audit/audisp-remote.conf
remote_server = 192.168.34.150
port = 60
##local_port =
transport = tcp
queue_file = /var/spool/audit/remote.log
mode = immediate
queue_depth = 10240
format = managed
network_retry_time = 1
max_tries_per_record = 3
max_time_per_record = 5
heartbeat_timeout = 0

network_failure_action = stop
disk_low_action = ignore
disk_full_action = warn_once
disk_error_action = warn_once
remote_ending_action = reconnect
generic_error_action = syslog
generic_warning_action = syslog
queue_error_action = stop
overflow_action = syslog
startup_failure_action = warn_once_continue

##krb5_principal =
##krb5_client_name = auditd
##krb5_key_file = /etc/audisp/audisp-remote.key

file: /etc/audit/auditd.conf
local_events = yes
write_logs = yes
log_file = /var/log/audit/audit.log
log_group = adm
log_format = NOLOG
flush = INCREMENTAL_ASYNC
freq = 50
max_log_file = 8
num_logs = 5
priority_boost = 4
name_format = NONE
##name = mydomain
max_log_file_action = ROTATE
space_left = 75
space_left_action = SYSLOG
verify_email = yes
action_mail_acct = root
admin_space_left = 50
admin_space_left_action = SUSPEND
disk_full_action = SUSPEND
disk_error_action = SUSPEND
use_libwrap = yes
tcp_listen_port = 60
tcp_listen_queue = 5
tcp_max_per_addr = 1
##tcp_client_ports = 1024-65535
tcp_client_max_idle = 0
transport = TCP
krb5_principal = auditd
##krb5_key_file = /etc/audit/audit.key
distribute_network = no
q_depth = 1200
overflow_action = SYSLOG
max_restarts = 10
plugin_dir = /etc/audit/plugins.d
end_of_event_timeout = 2

server side
file: /etc/audit/auditd.conf
local_events = yes
write_logs = yes
log_file = /var/log/audit/audit.log
log_group = adm
log_format = ENRICHED
flush = INCREMENTAL_ASYNC
freq = 50
max_log_file = 8
num_logs = 5
priority_boost = 4
name_format = NONE
##name = mydomain
max_log_file_action = ROTATE
space_left = 75
space_left_action = SYSLOG
verify_email = yes
action_mail_acct = root
admin_space_left = 50
admin_space_left_action = SUSPEND
disk_full_action = SUSPEND
disk_error_action = SUSPEND
use_libwrap = yes
tcp_listen_port = 60
tcp_listen_queue = 5
tcp_max_per_addr = 1
##tcp_client_ports = 1024-65535
tcp_client_max_idle = 0
transport = TCP
krb5_principal = auditd
##krb5_key_file = /etc/audit/audit.key
distribute_network = no
q_depth = 1200
overflow_action = SYSLOG
max_restarts = 10
plugin_dir = /etc/audit/plugins.d
end_of_event_timeout = 2

unfortunately, the file /var/log/audit/audit.log on the server contains information only about the server, there is no information that the client should transmit.
Could you tell me please what did I do wrong? How should I tune in?
